# How to create modify QR code design in react native?

Tags: react-native, qr-code

In my react native application I have to generate QR code in customise way.

I am using this library to generate QR code `react-native-qrcode-svg` and it is working well.
But the design is not able to make same as requirement. I am trying to achieve like that

```js
<QRCode
  color={Colors.DARK_PURPLE}
  value={item.value}
  size={windowWidth - 140}
  backgroundColor={'transparent'}
  logo={{url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/logosmalltransparen.png',}}
  logoSize={50}
  logoMargin={50}
/>
```

Can I change the design style and make the same as `rainbow` does show.

I have to make QR code like that :-

[image]

And currently I am able to made like that :-

[image]

Can I modify the design like my requirement, someone please help me